# How to create a new Xcode 5 project that is backwards compatible with iOS 5.0? - Getting missing Storyboard error

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5, storyboard, backwards-compatibility

Our client requires an iPad/iPhone app that covers iOS 5.0 - iOS 7.0.

1. I created a new project in Xcode 5
2. In build settings I changed the architecture to standard Standard *armv7*, *armv7s*
3. I clicked on the Main.storyboard and made sure that the interface builder settings were:
            Opens in: Default (5.0)
            Builds for: iOS 5 and Later
            View as: iOS 6.1 and Earlier
4. In Deployment Info I changed the Deployment Target to 5.0

I can see my old simulators now, but running an empty single application project in iOS 5.0 simulator gives me this missing storyboard errors that many have reported:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception '`NSInvalidArgumentException`', reason: 'Could not find a storyboard named 'Main' in bundle NSBundle

I can see a red "missing" *storyboard* in "*Copy Bundle Resources*" - no solutions on here work, i.e. `deleting/re-adding/clean/compile`. I noticed that clicking "Localization-English" box on Interface Builder make the red file look normal, but I still get this missing error when I run the simulator.

I'm thinking that the only way is to create a project in Xcode 4 build with iOS 5 compatible code and just test and make amendments to it later with iOS 7.0

Any thoughts?

Comment: I was looking for this documentation too.  View As lets you see how it looks when it runs on the device, it doesn't change the internal storage of your nib or storyboard.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TransitionGuide/SupportingEarlieriOS.html

Comment: @cathal you create new projects as way to new one by default. only archive ios5 target use below condition

Answer (score 4):

Select Main.storyboard and make the following changes to Localization section in File Inspector.

[image: Changes to Main.storyboard]