# button title not displayed on ios5 in xcode5

Tags: ios5, uibutton, storyboard, xcode5

I created my application using storyboard.The app working fine in ios6 and ios7.But the button title not displayed in ios5+ and the button created with the background image in storyboard.

Comment: Not enough information.

Comment: This is perfect solution. Note this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19381522/how-to-create-a-new-xcode-5-project-that-is-backwards-compatible-with-ios-5-0